# How would you prevent users from spoofing a username in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

How can I prevent a user from spoofing a username by posting something to Firebase using, say, a valid auth uid, but a wrong "username"?

I could JUST store the UID, but then I'd have to make the client look up all UID's all the time.  It would be ideal if I could somehow make sure that the username specified is the same as the logged in users' username.

Ideally, I would make a rule that looks like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "chat":{
          "messages":{
            ".read":true,
            ".write":true,
            "$message":{
              ".read":true,
              ".write":true
              ".validate": "newData.child('name').val() == auth.facebook.displayName"
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

But the auth variable does not contain the username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most such cases, developers store the complete information of all users under a `/users` node in their Firebase. E.g.

```
/
  users
    twitter:478645678
      username: "puf"
      displayName: "Frank van Puffelen"
  chat
    messages
      -J328764236789
        author: twitter:478645678
        name: "puf"
        message: "Hello world"
```

With this structure, you can cross-reference the username to `/users/<uid>/username`:

```
".validate": "newData.child('name').val() == root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('username').val()"
```